# SQL statement outputs only last row of list

Tags: python, sql, database, execute

Below is the code inserting data from list appstore into Applestore table created in database ios.db

```
 import sqlite3
    connection = sqlite3.connect("ios.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for p in appstore[1:]: 
        format_str = """INSERT INTO Applestore (id, track_name, size_bytes, currency, price, rating_count_tot, rating_count_ver, user_rating, user_rating_ver, ver,  cont_rating, prime_genre, sup_devices_num, ipadSc_url, lang_num, vpp_lic) 
        VALUES ("{id}", "{track_name}", "{size_bytes}", "{currency}", "{price}", "{rating_count_tot}", "{rating_count_ver}", "{user_rating}", "{user_rating_ver}", "{ver}",  "{cont_rating}", "{prime_genre}", "{sup_devices_num}", "{ipadSc_url}", "{lang_num}", "{vpp_lic}");""" 
        sql_command = format_str.format(id = p[0],track_name = p[1],size_bytes = p[2],currency = p[3],price = p[4],rating_count_tot = p[5],rating_count_ver = p[6], user_rating = p[7], user_rating_ver = p[8], ver = p[9], cont_rating = p[10], prime_genre = p[11], sup_devices_num = p[12], ipadSc_url = p[13], lang_num = p[14], vpp_lic = p[15]) 

    cursor.execute(sql_command)


    connection.commit()

    connection.close()
```

This only outputs the last row

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("ios.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Applestore""")
print("fetchall:")
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

After adding the mentioned suggestions this is how the code looks like:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("ios.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
for p in appstore:
    format_str = """INSERT INTO Applestore (id, track_name, size_bytes, currency, price, rating_count_tot, rating_count_ver, user_rating, user_rating_ver, ver,  cont_rating, prime_genre, sup_devices_num, ipadSc_url, lang_num, vpp_lic) 
    VALUES (id, track_name, size_bytes, currency, price, rating_count_tot, rating_count_ver, user_rating, user_rating_ver, ver,  cont_rating, prime_genre, sup_devices_num, ipadSc_url, lang_num, vpp_lic);""" 
    #sql_command = format_str.format(id = p[0],track_name = p[1],size_bytes = p[2],currency = p[3],price = p[4],rating_count_tot = p[5],rating_count_ver = p[6], user_rating = p[7], user_rating_ver = p[8], ver = p[9], cont_rating = p[10], prime_genre = p[11], sup_devices_num = p[12], ipadSc_url = p[13], lang_num = p[14], vpp_lic = p[15]) 
    cursor.execute(format_str, (*p[1:16]))


connection.commit()
connetion.close()
```

Error: function takes at most 2 arguments (17 given)

Comment: No, it prints out all of the results from your database; you only have 1 result in there because `c.execute` is outside of your `for p in appstore[1:]: ` loop, so only the last INSERT gets performed. You should not be building you SQL query with string formatting; this is an SQL injection risk and leads to illegible queries

Comment: @roganjosh Agree, but this is an other issue.

Comment: 7     sql_command = format_str.format(id = p[0],track_name = p[1],size_bytes = p[2],currency = p[3],price = p[4],rating_count_tot = p[5],rating_count_ver = p[6], user_rating = p[7], user_rating_ver = p[8], ver = p[9], cont_rating = p[10], prime_genre = p[11], sup_devices_num = p[12], ipadSc_url = p[13], lang_num = p[14], vpp_lic = p[15])
----> 8     cursor.execute(sql_command)
      9 
     10 

OperationalError: near "HOOK": syntax error

Comment: @roganjosh This is the only way i figured how to get the job done. Im still a novice so just bare with me a little. When i put cursor.execute(sql_command) in the for loop it gives me the above error

Comment: If you have any other way it might be done your help would be really appreciated. Ive been trying for the past 3 days and im getting frustrated afff

Comment: `format_str = """INSERT INTO Applestore (id, track_name, size_bytes, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ....)"""` (obviously with `...` replaced with all the remaining values; I'm not typing the whole thing out in a comment). Then `c.execute(format_str, *p[:16])`. Don't forget the `*` just before the `p` when you execute the query. This is the "unpacking" or "splat" operator that you can research another time

Comment: @roganjosh still getting an error bro. Edited the post. Any suggenstions?

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the SQL Command each time you loop in your for-loop.

You may put `cursor.execute(sql_command)` inside the for-loop,
directly below `sql_command = ...`